# Добавить синонимы [распознавание-текста] и [распознавание-символов] к метке [ocr]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю добавить синонимы [распознавание-текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0) и [распознавание-символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2) к метке [ocr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocr).

Я думаю, что новички могут не знать термин ***OCR*** (*Optical Character Recognition*).
Синонимы могут помочь повесить данную метку, а также узнать сам термин.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аргумент "новички могут не знать" сомнительный: на текущий момент нет ни одного вопроса с меткой "распознавание текста" и все 43 вопроса висят на метке ocr. Но не это главное.

Мы обычно стараемся, что основная метка была на русском языке, когда это возможно. Как по мне "распознавание текста" отлично подходит на роль основной метки, к которой можно сделать синонимы и ocr и "распознавание символов".

> Распознавание текста - более частная метка, чем распознавание символов.

Термин "распознавание текста" для меня более привычный и чаще употребляемый, чем "распознавание символов", но я не специалист. Но если это верно и более важно, чем распространённость термина, тогда логично оставить "распознавание текста" и "распознавание символов" независимыми метками, а ocr сделать вспомогательным синонимом к "распознавание символов".

Comment: Распознавание текста - более частная метка, чем распознавание символов.

Comment: Не все вопросы висят на метке [tag:ocr]. Достаточно [поискать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) по фразе `распознавание символов` (или `текста`), чтобы убедиться в этом. Найдётся много вопросов по теме с достаточно специфичными метками, но [tag:ocr] используют далеко не все. Я предполагаю, что многие просто не знают этот термин.

Comment: @AK, например, в распознавании текста могут применять словари для определения наиболее вероятного символа. А при распознавании отдельных символов - нет. При распознавании каких-нибудь бланков ЕГЭ автокоррекция под словарь тоже не в тему. И автомобильный номер - тоже не очень текст.

Comment: Давайте попробуем закрыть этот вопрос. Последний вариант, предложенный Вами, лично мне кажется отличным решением. Он следует принципам ruSO (в плане русскоязычного наименования) и делает нахождение метки проще.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Я всегда придерживаюсь принципа "обсуждение меток должно длиться не менее двух недель". Вдруг придёт кто-то, просматривающий мету раз в неделю да и предложит какие-то отличные аргументы и совершенно иной вариант, который сейчас просто никому не пришёл в голову? Сомневаюсь, что такое будет именно в этом случае, но мало ли какой чёрный лебедь прилетит? Подождём ещё немного, потом закроем тему.

Comment: @AK Думаю, теперь прошло достаточно времени :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Спасибо за напоминание. Создал синоним, теперь ocr будет заменяться на распознавание-символов. Все вопросы с меткой ocr перенёс на метку распознавание-символов (43 штуки), в течение 15 минут должны обновиться кеши сайта.